# Calendar in type script shows a strange unicode inside each element

Tags: .net, typescript

I use a calendar from library in a type script but it shows a strange unicode inside each element in it beside the title..
what the cause of this problem, and how to resolve it?

I tried to resolved it, but i cannot.
Help please..

Comment: What does `strange unicode` mean? JavaScript and TypeScript strings are Unicode. Strings don't have titles either. Are you generating HTML that doesn't look right? Are you sure the problem isn't in the data you use? Or that the code doesn't generate invalid HTML? We can't guess what the problem is with just `strange unicode`

Comment: Which lib are you using? How are you using it? Show us the HTML & TS code. What is this "strange unicode" looking like exactly? Show us a screenshot.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.